# Swift protocol extension with property conforming to protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I declared a protocol like so

```
protocol JSONConnection {
  var request: NSURLRequest { get set }
  var session: NSURLSession { get set }
  var jsonRootObject: JSONSerializable? { get set }
}
```

Here, the JSONSerializable is not an actual type, it is another protocol that I declared like so:

```
protocol JSONSerializable {
  func readFromJSON(json: JSON) throws
}
```

So, in fact, this JSONConnection protocol requires a variable called jsonRootObject that just needs to conform to the JSONSerializable protocol.

Fine.

---

Now, for the implementations.

I created a class called JSONStockDetailRootObject that conforms to the JSONSerializable protocol.

```
class JSONStockDetailRootObject: JSONSerializable
```

And I wanted to create a StockConnection class that conforms to the JSONConnection protocol.

```
class StockConnection: JSONConnection {
  var request: NSURLRequest
  var session: NSURLSession
  var jsonRootObject: JSONStockDetailRootObject?
}
```

I thought that, if I had a jsonRootObject variable of a type that conformed to the JSONSerializable protocol, then this class StockConnection would in turn conform to the JSONConnection protocol ... but no.

**The compiler claims: "Protocol requires property 'jsonRootObject' with type 'JSONSerializable?'**

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: you changed the type of `jsonRootObject`. Now it no longer conforms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, the class `StockConnection` does not contain any valid implementation of the blueprint `var jsonRootObject: JSONSerializable? { get set }`, which it promises to implement by conforming to `JSONConnection`. Note that in the context of `jsonRootObject`, `JSONSerializable` is a *type*, and even if `JSONStockDetailRootObject` *conforms* to `JSONSerializable`, it cannot be treated as the *same* type.

You can solve this by introducing a typealias, say `T`, (to use as `jsonRootObject` type) into protocol `JSONConnection`; where `T` is constrained to types conforming to `JSONSerializable`.

```
protocol JSONSerializable {
    func readFromJSON(json: JSON) throws
}

protocol JSONConnection {
    typealias T: JSONSerializable
    var request: NSURLRequest { get set }
    var session: NSURLSession { get set }
    var jsonRootObject: T? { get set }
}

class JSONStockDetailRootObject: JSONSerializable {
    func readFromJSON(json: JSON) throws ...
}

class StockConnection: JSONConnection {
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest()
    var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession()
    var jsonRootObject: JSONStockDetailRootObject?
}
```

Since `JSONStockDetailRootObject` conforms `JSONSerializable`, the implementation of `jsonRootObject` in `StockConnection` above is valid conformance of the blueprint `var jsonRootObject: T? { get set }` in protocol `JSONConnection`.

Comment: Great, that worked! Thanks for the very clear explanation!

Comment: @FredA. Happy to help.

Comment: Doing this today throws an error saying type alias requires an associated type, which causes a whole mess of other errors.

Comment: @Bot I haven’t touched Swift in a few years, but feel free to update this answer as you see fit, in case you resolve the whole mess of other errors.